# An exercise on compactness on $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis

If $g$ is a nonnegative measurable function on $[0,1]$, and let $K=\{f\in L^1([0,1]) :|f|\leq g \,\,\,\,  a.e.\}$, prove the following:

(a)$K$ is closed,

(b)If $K$ is compact then $g\in L^1$.

Part (a) is easy, any help with part (b)?

Actually the exercise has a part (c) also, which i initially thought it was trivial but it seems it has some work. Any suggestion is welcome!

(c)If $g=1$ prove that $K$ is not compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Consider the functions $f_n = g\cdot \chi_{\{g\le n\}}.$

---

Added later: Since the problem has a part (c) now, let me give a hint for that: Let

$$f(x) = 0, x\in[-1,0), \,\,f(x) = 1, x\in[0,1).$$

Then extend $f$ to $\mathbb {R}$ by making it periodic with period $2.$ Consider the functions $f_n(x) = f(2^nx), x\in [0,1].$ (I see now Ian earlier had also suggested "oscillation" as the key to this one.)

Comment: Nice solution and thank you very much, if you have any hints for the third part also i would be very happy..

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking the sequence sin(nx) but i found it very difficult to prove that it doesn't have a pointwise convergent subsequence. Your example is easier to treat.

Answer (score 4):

Consider bounded cutoffs of $g$, i.e. $g_n(x)=\begin{cases} g(x) & \text{if } g(x) \in [0,n] \\ 0 &  \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. These are all in $K$, and converge pointwise to $g$. By compactness there is an $L^1$-convergent subsequence whose limit is in $K$. Can you use this to argue that in fact $g \in K$, hence $g \in L^1$?

In part c, the basic recipes for making a sequence of $L^p$ functions with no $L^p$-convergent subsequence are:

1. A sequence whose $L^p$ norms blow up monotonically. For example, $f_n(x)=n$. This one comes directly from the general theory of metric spaces, nothing special here.
2. A sequence which converges pointwise to zero but has a fixed $L^p$ norm. To make this actually work, you must violate the hypotheses of the Vitali Convergence Theorem. There are basically only two ways to do this:

   - You can make a sequence which blows up on small sets. For example, $n \chi_{[0,1/n]}$.
   - You can make a sequence which moves a positive amount of "mass" to infinity. For example, $\chi_{[n,n+1]}$. This is only possible in an infinite measure space.
3. A sequence which oscillates more and more rapidly as $n$ increases.

The first two won't work in your case. Play with the third one.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comments were very helpful. My intuition drove me to the same point also, i was just hoping to find probably a theoretical solution using probably some result. The problem with the constructive way is that it takes time and effort to write down clearly. Thanks again!

Comment: That was a very good hint for c. I hadn't seen this when I gave an example above.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\int_0^1 g(t)\,{\rm d}t = \infty$. Now decompose $[0,1]$ into sets where $g\leqslant n$ What can you say about the the sequence of restrictions of $g$ to these sets?